# Vbscript to ping a list of machines and check if the IP-Addresses has changed and if they have changed send a Mail

Tags: vbscript

I search for a Script that pings a List of machines and if a IP has changed send a warning mail. Hope somebody can help me.

Greets Mohrjon

Comment: -1: That's nice, what have you done yourself so far to accomplish this? Also, have you considered reading "How to ask a question"? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Is the ping sufficient information to know that the IP address has changed? - what if the network goes down for a short period of time whilst the script is running?

Anyhow these are three subs i have which i have bodged together which should do what you need

Firstly i would iterate through a text file (csv) to get my ip address, and in this case the name and email

```
Sub Open_Master_File()

Do While objTextFile.AtEndOfStream <> True

    strLine = objTextFile.ReadLine

    'skip if comment line found
    If inStr(1,strLine, "'") Then

    ElseIf inStr(1,strLine, ",") Then

        arrayMasterFile = split(strLine, ",")
        strStoreName =  arrayMasterFile(0)
        strComputerIP =  arrayMasterFile(1)
        strEmailRecipient =  arrayMasterFile(2)

        'Call ping function to check for online/offline computers
        Call Ping_Computer()    


    End If

Loop    

'Release Memory 
objTextFile.Close()
Set objTextFile = Nothing
Set objMasterFSO = Nothing

End Sub
```

next i ping to each of the ip's (btw this will only show if the ip is offline, can you guarantee that the ip is online all of the time?)

```
Sub Ping_Computer()

Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

'Run the ping program 3 times, with a 2000ms delay on each, 0 = don't display cmd prompt
'All three pings must be successful for CBool = true
pingSuccessful = Not CBool(wshShell.run("ping -n 3 -w 2000 " & strComputerIP,0,True))

If pingSuccessful = True Then

Else

      Call Send_EMail()

End If

'Release memory
Set wshShell = Nothing

End Sub
```

Send an email

```
Sub Send_Email()

Set objEmail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")  

strSubject = ""
strEmailFrom = ""
strBody = ""


objEmail.Subject = strSubject
objEmail.From = strEmailFrom
objEmail.To = strEmailRecipient

'Use Microsoft schemas for emails
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = cdoNTLM
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = strServer
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = cMailPort
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Update

objEmail.Textbody = strBody

'Check if an error occurs during the send email process, do not stop program
On Error Resume Next

objEmail.Send

'error on send  
If Err.Number <> 0 Then

Else

End If

'clear errors
On Error Goto 0

'Release Memory
Set objEmail = Nothing

End Sub
```